# Why Can't I Get Focus With Opera?

Tags: javascript

Not sure what I did wrong here. In parent window I have:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.new-window').click(function(){
            var posY = ($(window).height()-550)/2;
            var posX = ($(window).width())/2;
            window.open(this.href, this.alt, "toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,scrollbars=1,screenX="+posX+",screenY="+posY+",status=0,menubar=0,width=550,height=550");
            setTimeout('new-window.focus()', 1);
            return false;
        });
and so on.....
```

And then on the child window I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var window_focus;

$(window).focus(function() {
    window_focus = true;
})
    .blur(function() {
        window_focus = false;
    });

$(document).one('ready',function() {
setInterval(function() { $('body').append('has focus? ' + window_focus + '<br>'); }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

to check child for forcus. "Undefined" is what I am getting from the child.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: For starters, in this code `setTimeout('new-window.focus()', 1);`, I don't see any variable defined called `new-window` and I think that's probably not even legal javascript since you can't use a dash in a variable name.

Comment: what should be there then?

Comment: I don't know because you don't show your HTML or explain what element in that HTML you want the focus on.

Comment: Let's say the body then. Focus on body of child window. It's the syntax that I need help with. I also noticed this may be only a problem with Opera, so I am needing cross-browser syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.new-window').click(function(){
        var posY = ($(window).height()-550)/2;
        var posX = ($(window).width())/2;
        var new_window = window.open(this.href, this.alt, "toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,scrollbars=1,screenX="+posX+",screenY="+posY+",status=0,menubar=0,width=550,height=550");
        setTimeout(function() {
            new_window.focus();
        }, 1);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Nope. Is it just Opera that refuses to do this right?

Comment: I found a different work around to my problem, but thanks for giving it a try. Marked as answer....

Comment: @mobilestimulus - it is not the correct use of Stack overflow to mark an answer as best answer that doesn't work.  You should make your own answer with what worked and mark that one.